# how to inject code to remove "add to cart" button + quantity selector in Square Online Editor

Tags: html, css, square

I am designing a website in square online editor and I would like to remove the"add to cart" button and the quantity selection bar.
Square editor does not allow me to directly edit the html or css code on the website, instead I have to use their "inject code" button.
However, I have tried this several times, I've tried injecting code into the page header, into the individual product pages, and have tried several bits of code(with and without /style tags)

Does anybody know how I could solve this?, thanks.

Here is some of the code I have tried to use:

---

```
.tag-hidecart .ProductItem-summary .ProductItem-details {
  .sqs-add-to-cart-button-wrapper, .product-quantity-input {
  display: none;
  }
}
```

---

```
.sqs-add-to-cart-button-wrapper {
    display: none !important;
}
```

---

```
script> document.head.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://sage123.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/lol.css">`); </script>
```

none of this worked and the button remained on the page.